# .NET 1.1 MSI installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-1.1

I have a .NET 1.1 msi installer and I'd like to install it on a Windows 10/2012 server. My question it is possible or hopeless trying?

Thank you.

Comment: that won't work. .net 1.1 is dead since Win7 timeframe and no longer supported. why do you want to do this? Does an old software require it?

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the answer. Yes, I would have liked to migrate a .NET 1.1 app onto a Win 2012 server.